# How can I use a queue with QProcess?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I have a slot that is called passing some arguments used in a QProcess.
I execute a external program with some of this arguments. 
The problem is that I want to have a queue for these processes, waiting until the previous process is finished to launch the next.

What do you think is the best/easiest way?

Here my method/slot:

```
void FirstCase::CallApp(QString text, QString pathAndFileName)
{
   QString command = QString("App1.exe %1 -Z %2").arg(pathAndFileName).arg(message); 
   QProcess* process = new QProcess(this);
   process->start(command);
}
```

**EDIT** Here the solution, if you need it:

Following the QStringList idea, my CallApp method just adds the command to the QStringList like:

```
list << command;
```

And then calls to Execute();

```
void FirstCase::Execute()
{
   if(!list_.isEmpty()&&!executing_)
    {
        QProcess* p = new QProcess(this);
        QString c = list_.takeFirst();
        p->start(c);
        executing_=TRUE;
        connect(p, SIGNAL(finished(int)),this,SLOT(ExecFinished()));
    }
}

void FirstCase::ExecFinished()
{
    executing__=FALSE;
    Execute();
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest to use the QStringList overload of start() with separated arguments. Otherwise you'll run into quoting issues pretty soon (e.g. if the program you execute has a space in its path). The QStringList() version does the quoting automatically.

Comment: You are using the the finished signal wrong, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a QString queue to queue up your commands and store them. Then, start from the top of the queue, start a new process and connect its finished() signal to a slot. When that process finishes, start a new process if the queue is not empty and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

The correct signature for `finished` function is;

```
void QProcess::finished ( int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus )
```

so you should connect like this;

```
connect(p, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)),this,SLOT(ExecFinished()));
```